# @AdditionalCriteria in combination with @OneToOne gives QueryException

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant, one-to-one

I'm trying to create a RESTful service. For multi tenancy I'm applying the @AdditionalCriteria annotation. However, when I join an entity using the @OneToOne annotation the following Exception is raised:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6174] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-
r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: No value was provided for the session property 
[SECURITYID]. This exception is possible when using additional criteria or 
tenant discriminator columns without specifying the associated contextual 
property. These properties must be set through Entity Manager, Entity Manager 
Factory or persistence unit properties. If using native EclipseLink, these 
properties should be set directly on the session.
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="readObject" referenceClass=Addresses 
sql="SELECT id, city, country, postalcode, province, security_id, street 
FROM addresses WHERE ((id = ?) AND (security_id = ?))")
```

I set the property [SECURITYID] at EntityManager level and without the join everything works just fine. But when I join an entity using the @OneToOne I see that property is not there. I don't have enough experience to determine if this is caused by me doing something wrong or if this is a bug. To me it looks like a different EntityManager is used to fetch the joined entity. But I'm guessing because of me lacking in knowledge. I also tried to set the properties on EntityManagerFactory level but to no avail.

Here is my setup.
Entity:

```
@Entity
@AdditionalCriteria("this.securityId=:SECURITYID")
@Table(name = "tasks", catalog = "catalog", schema = "schema")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries(
{
  @NamedQuery(name = "Tasks.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Tasks t")

})
public class Tasks implements Serializable
{
...
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="service_address_id")
  private Addresses serviceAddress;

...
}
```

RESTFacade class

```
@Stateless
@Path("tasks")
public class TasksFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Tasks>
{
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UnitName")
  private EntityManager em;

...

  @java.lang.Override
  protected EntityManager getEntityManager()
  {
    // Temp! REMOVE WHEN DONE
    sessionId = "123456789";

    Identifier.setIdentity(em,sessionId);
    em.setProperty("SECURITYID",Identifier.securityId);
    em.setProperty("USERID",Identifier.userId);

    return em;
  }
```

Thanks & Rgds,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this is related to caching.

Normally the tenant property would be set on the EntityManagerFactory, not the EntityManager.  This would mean you have a different EntityManagerFactory for each tenant.  You could also define the tenant property in your persistence.xml and have a different persistence unit per tenant.

If you need to set the tenant per EntityManager, then you need to disable the shared cache, or setting the cache mode to protected.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Single-Table_Multi-Tenancy#Setting_Properties_and_Caching_Scope

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed the caching. I switched it off and it now works. I'll read up on it at the suggested link and make the proper adjustments. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For reference the property to be disabled is `eclipselink.cache.shared.default`

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```